# SIP headers overview

Tags: networking, sip

Is there any table or list available online where are listed all SIP headers and where it is specified for each one of them, whether it is used by the UAC, UAS or by the network (and removed before reaching destination)?

Comment: By SIP here, you do mean the "Session Initiation Protocol" correct? And if so, have you seen the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt)?

Comment: yes, but I was wondering if there is a table or something like that, something very succinct

Comment: RFC 3261 defines the core headers, but there are hundreds of RFCs extending the protocol, so it seems a reasonable question to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking for this, the [IANA registry for SIP parameters](http://www.iana.org/assignments/sip-parameters). That tells you headers, parameters, response codes, and so on, and which RFCs define those bits.